# Rails: Getting the All Users Where User has not followed him

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to list all those users with whom `current_user` is not following so that current_user can follow him

User Model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follower_relationships, foreign_key: :following_id, class_name: 'Follow'
  has_many :followers, through: :follower_relationships, source: :follower
  has_many :following_relationships, foreign_key: :follower_id, class_name: 'Follow'
  has_many :following, through: :following_relationships, source: :following
end
```

And the Follow class looks like this.

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :follower, foreign_key: 'follower_id', class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :following, foreign_key: 'following_id', class_name: 'User'
end
```

I know i can get all the followings like this:

```
current_user.following
```

I want to get all Users with whom current_user is not following.
I tried to do like this but i could not do :(

```
User.all.where.not(following: current_user.following)
```

I will try to give following example if you don't understand question properly.

Let say there are User `A , B , C , D ,E` . Lets say `A` is following `B` and `C` . I want to display `D` And `E` so that `A` knows he is not following `D` and `E`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by following way

first find ids of all the users that current_user is following

```
ids = current_user.followings.pluck(:id)
```

and then find all the users except that ids

```
users = User.where("id NOT IN ?", ids)
```

This might be help you

Comment: Hi thanks :) It worked and i have no other alternative. However i do want to give some suggestion . In rails 4 we can use where not like this . User.where.not(id: ids) . By the way thanks